# Why my game will crash when some ads provided by sdk showed?

Tags: android, crash, ads, godot

I create a mobile(android) game by godot, and use an ad provider sdk.
Some ads can show normally, but few ads will crash my game.
The error info like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4akJS.png)

It seems that my game was killed because it was in background task.
I want to konw what caused this problem??
Which direction can I dig in?
Thanks guys!!!

I try to use the plugin code written by others who never encounter this, but the situation is still buggy.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar enough with Godot to help you out with the specifics of this problem, I can give you some general advice. If your target platform is Android, you should familiarize yourself with the Android SDK as much as possible. You should know about the Activity class, intents, fragments and a whole bunch of other Android OS concepts before trying to distribute an app for Android. That would generally put you in a better position to resolve issues like this. Just my thoughts, don't know how helpful I am being here...